# Does it needed to regenerate wiremock after API changing on counterpart's service?

Tags: wiremock

I'm using wiremock to mock another service while testing the current service.
Does it needed to regenerate wiremock on the current service after API changing on counterpart's service?

Comment: What do you mean by regenerate wiremock? What is changing with the counterpart's service? WireMock is a mock web server, so if the API that your app is consuming changes, you will need to update WireMock with those changes. (for example, app used to consume `/login-v1` but now consumes `/login-v2`)

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you. What do you mean by `to update WireMock with those changes`? Just change settings text file or recompile?

Comment: You'd need to update your mappings or stubs in order to correctly match on the new requests.